# "wrong output format Unexpected end of file - token expected" error on Codeforces

Tags: python

the problem on Codeforces is:

```
- input w (watermelon weight) is between 1 and 100.
- if watermelon can be split into two parts, each weighing even number of kilos, print YES, otherwise print NO
```

My code (Python 3) is

```
w = input()
w = int(w)
if w >= 4 and w%2 == 0:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

and when I input `8`, I get the output `YES`, as it should be.

However, when I submit my file, it says `wrong answer to test 1` and

```
Input
8
Participant's output
Jury's answer
YES

Checker comment:
wrong output format Unexpected end of file - token expected
```

Can someone kindly explain what am I missing? I tried to find this exact error and figure it out but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with a help from my friend, so I just wanted to answer my own question in case anyone else encountered the same problem.

I was using Jupyter notebook for solving this, so my file had an .ipynb extension, which is why the solver on site didn't recognize the actual code. The solution was uploading a .py extension (for example, copy/pasting the code in notepad and giving it a .py extension), then it was accepted.